# Java SWT remove element from ListViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm writing a GUI with SWT. You can choose file/s by click on button(like Browse) and they added to a ListViewer by their name. I've created new button to remove files from the list but its dont work for me.
This is the needed piece of codes I guess:

```
    ListViewer listViewer = new ListViewer(shlPmcompare, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    List list = listViewer.getList();
    list.setBounds(331, 11, 305, 100);

    btnBrowse.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            FileDialog fileBrowse = new FileDialog(shlPmcompare, SWT.MULTI);
            fileBrowse.setFilterExtensions(new String[] {"*.txt"});
            String filePath = fileBrowse.open();
            if (filePath != null) {
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                String[] files = fileBrowse.getFileNames();
                for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
                  buf.append(fileBrowse.getFilterPath());
                  if (buf.charAt(buf.length() - 1) != File.separatorChar) {
                    buf.append(File.separatorChar);
                  }
                  buf.append(files[i]);
                  buf.append("\n");
                }
                for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
                    list.add(files[i], 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnRemoveFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            IStructuredSelection selectionFile = (IStructuredSelection)listViewer.getSelection();
            List RemoveFile = (List)selectionFile.getFirstElement();
            if(RemoveFile == null) {
                MessageDialog.openError(shlPmcompare, "Removing Error", "You need to select file first.");
                return;
            }
            list.remove(RemoveFile);
            listViewer.refresh(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a JFace viewer like `ListViewer` with a few exceptions you should not call any methods on the underlying control (`List` in this case). The viewer manages the control and you should only uses the viewer's methods to change it.

To remove a selection from the list you call the `ListViewer` `remove` method, **not** `List.remove`.

So this is a viewer which just displays some strings:

```
ListViewer listViewer = new ListViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
listViewer.getList().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

listViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
contents.add("a");
contents.add("b");
contents.add("c");

listViewer.setInput(contents);

Button btnRemoveFile = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
btnRemoveFile.setText("Remove");
btnRemoveFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
      IStructuredSelection selectionFile = listViewer.getStructuredSelection();
      final Object removeFile = selectionFile.getFirstElement();
      // TODO check for no selection

      listViewer.remove(removeFile);

      contents.remove(removeFile);
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. it still don't work, its always enter to the IF statement..
2. I didn't understand what should I writ in the 'TODO' section.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code to help any further, we need to see how you are putting content in to the list viewer. What is your content viewer? what is your `setInput` call? Show us a proper [mcve].

Comment: You are adding things directly to the `List` control - you can't do that if you are using `ListViewer`. Either get rid of the `ListViewer` altogether and just use `List` or continue with `ListViewer` and use a content provider, label provider and a `setInput` call. You can't mix things up like this.

Comment: can you please edit the code you put here? I want see what you mean and compare with my code.. it will be easier for me. thanks a lot.

Comment: Why I cant use `listViewer.setBounds()` ?  I dont see the list in my GUI...

Comment: You can use setBounds if you want but it is poor practise. Learn to use Layouts.